# Socket writing errors

Tags: java, android, sockets

I'm new to Android Java, but I'm trying to build an application that backups a file to my computer from my android phone through the internet.

I've got a problem with writing a socket, the Socket looks like this:

```
mySock = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 8001);
```

This server runs on my computer, when opening on browser (on the computer) it shows my Desktop.

I am using a real phone, not the emulator

yes, I have INTERNET permission, and I have already tried "10.0.2.2" but it didn't seem to work as well, I always got the message on my LogCat that says

```
failed to connect to /127.0.0.1 (port 8001):
connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (connection refused)
```

when putting a breakpoint on the line of the socket and debugging, when getting to the socket writing line, it seem to have a problem writing the Socket, did I write it wrong in some way? I know the parameters are fine, please help!

Edit:
So now I disabled the firewall on the Ubuntu, and when I put the Ip 10.0.2.2 it actually stops to... I guess to try and copy? after a few seconds it prints the next message:

```
connect failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)
```

someone knows what might be the problem now?

Comment: are you using emulator or real device?

Comment: `127.0.0.1` is the address normally associated with the [loopbackk interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback) so you won't manage to connect to your desktop from your phone on it. Use the IP of your desktop instead. Also, note that if you don't have a public IP for your desktop, your phone will have to be on the same network for this to work.

Comment: I am using a real phone, if I haven't said it before. @Coderji

Comment: Where does '10.0.2.2' come from?  That really your IP address?

Comment: @MartinJames I saw it somewhere in the site here, that to connect with the server on my pc I need to type 10.0.2.2, I can't remember the exact explanation given, but it seems to do something at the moment and I'm looking for an answer how to solve it

Answer (score 0):

To access your computer you have to use your PC IP neither localhost nor 10.0.2.2
in order to get PC IP you have to go

`start -> cmd -> ipconfig`

then search for IPv4 copy the IP and paste it in your URL it should look like this:

```
     mySock = new Socket("192.168.0.101", 8001);
```

hope this works too for you, give me a feedback

**P.S: if it didnt work turn off the firewall and any anti-virus application you have**

Comment: Still doesn't work, does it have something to do with the fact I'm working on Ubuntu? @Coderji

Comment: im not sure about the security in Ubuntu.. but if you have any firewall or any thing that may block the communication. you should terminate it temporary..

Comment: read Bran hein answer in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255406/trouble-connecting-android-bluetooth-client-socket-to-ubuntu-server-socket) hope it this is what you are missing

Comment: Okay so I found how to disable the firewall on the Ubuntu, and I tried again some of the IPs I saw on the net and now that I typed in 10.0.2.2 it gives me this Error `EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)` @Coderji

Comment: ?? 192.168 is unrouteable.

Comment: 10.0.2.2 is only used when you are testing in emulator.. because emulator takes the normal localhost IP which is 127.0.0.1 so to connect to your server localhost you use another Localhost IP which is 10.0.2.2. but you are developing using your phone so you need to provide your PC IP address.. follow this [tutorial](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/17012/how-to-find-your-ip-address-in-ubuntu/) to get IP address in Ubuntu

Comment: @Coderji man when I put my own IP it still prints the ECONNREFUSED error, still wont work :\

Comment: can you add the manifest... I want to know what permissions you added... did you add the `Internet` and `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` permissions?

Comment: @Coderji Yeah I wrote it... I did

Comment: according to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522396/tcp-ip-client-ehostunreach-no-route-to-host) it seems that it is a network problem not an android issue, the PC and the mobile are both connected to the same router right?... and try to open a server through your mobile browser to make sure it is android or network problem